# Ajax call from dropdown select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to make an Ajax request to the page specified in the drop down menu. I have successfully used most of my script code in binding a mouse click to table rows, but it does not work in this case when I try it here. I get ReferenceError: fnsuccess is not defined. I did not get this ReferenceError when I used most of this script to bind a mouse click.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function isValid(frm){
                $("#courseinfo").hide();
                $("#frm").validate();

                var four04 = $("#frm :selected").val();
                console.log('Testing console');

                if (four04 == "404")
                {
                    console.log("404");
                    var txt = ($(this).text());

                    $.ajax({url:"404.json", data:{coursename:txt}, type:"GET", dataType:"json",
                    success:fnsuccess, error:fnerror});

                    function fnsuccess(serverReply) {
                        if (serverReply && serverReply.info) {
                            $("#infohere").text(serverReply.info);
                            $("#courseinfo").show();
                        } else
                        fnerror();
                    }
                    function fnerror() {
                        alert("Error occurred");
                        $("#courseinfo").hide();
                    }                   
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log("else 404");
                }
        }
    </script>
```

Course -->
                Rating               
                404 error            
                403 error

Fix:

```
    <script>
        function isValid(frm){
            $("#otherPageContent").hide();
            $("#frm").validate();

            var dropDownSelected = $("#frm :selected").val();

            if (dropDownSelected == "404")
            {
                var txt = ($(this).text());

                $.ajax({url:"404_error.json", 
                    data:{coursename:txt}, 
                    type:"GET", 
                    dataType:"json",
                    success:fnsuccess, 
                    error: function(xhr, status, error){
                        $("#infohere").text(
                            "The requested page was: 404_error.json" + 
                            ". The error number returned was: " + xhr.status + 
                            ". The error message was: " + error);
                        $("#otherPageContent").show();
                    }
                }); // end of ajax                                      
            } // end of if 404

            function fnsuccess(serverReply) {
                if (serverReply && serverReply.info) {
                    $("#infohere").text(serverReply.info);
                    $("#otherPageContent").show();
                } 
            }
            return false;   // pause message on screen
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Seems you're using the functions `fnsuccess` and `fnerror` before they are defined. Move the `$.ajax call` to below those functions.

Comment: You forgot to pass arguments to the function `fnsuccess(serverReply)` in success of ajax call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define  `function fnsuccess(serverReply)` and  `fnerror` outside `isValid function`

Comment: A bit more explanation / context would be very helpful to other viewers.